# mysqlworkbench after cmd mysql startup went wrong

Tags: mysql

i have problems with my mysql server. I have installed the newest mysqlserver but having problems after starting my server from command line on localhost. Before that i was running xammp. The problem is that when starting from command line and not from xammp, mysqlworkbench shows me tables from another datadir when connecting with database . I really don't know how to fix my problem.

Comment: This probably belongs on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have two installations of MySQL: one installed normally and one installed through XAMPP. When starting MySQL through XAMPP it will start the one it installed, when started through the command line it installs the one that is installed natively. They both bind to the same port (so you can only have one active at a time) so MySQL Workbench will display the contents of the MySQL server that is started.

Because you have two installations of MySQL you should either only use one of them (and possibly remove the other) or only start the one that you need to access.